# iPhone gallery app crops photo to 3:2 from 4:3 aspect ratio, how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gallery, aspect-ratio

The photo taken using the `UIImagePickerController` is of 4:3 aspect ratio. However, the full screen aspect ratio is 3:2. So the gallery app is doing some magic to show the photo as 3:2 aspect ratio. When you zoom out in the full screen view, the photo appears in 4:3 aspect ratio. Can anyone shed light on how it could be done? I've been breaking my head for the past two weeks on this.

Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: Isn't it just using a `UIImageView` with a [`contentMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` (or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fit a 4:3 image into a 3:2 space you can either match the height or match the width.

If you were to match the height then you'd turn the 3 in 4:3 into the 2 in 3:2. So you'd scale the entire image by 2/3. Since you'd be scaling width and height by the same amount, the effective height after scaling would be the 4 from 4:3 scaled by 2/3, to give 8/3 — a bit less than three. You'd therefore not quite fill the screen.

Conversely, if you were to match the width then you'd turn the 4 in 4:3 into the 3 in 3:2. So you'd scale the entire image by 3/4. Since you'd be scaling width and height by the same amount, the effective height at the end would be the 3 from 4:3 scaled by 3/4, to give 9/4 — a bit more than two. You'll therefore slightly more than fill the screen.

So that the photos app does is display pictures with an initial zoom so as to fit the width of the stored image to the width of the display. If the stored image is 3264x2448 (which I think it is on the iPhone 4S and the 5) then on an iPhone 4s — using points rather than pixels — it's scaled by a ratio of 480/3264. If you work that out, it gives the image a final height of very close to 360pt, 40pt wider than the screen.

In terms of UIKit, that probably means putting a `UIImage` inside a `UIScrollView` and setting the initial value of `zoomScale` to 480/3264 (ie, approximately 0.15). The scroll view can help you with zooming in and out though there's still some manual work to be done — see e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content). By setting a `minimumZoomScale` of 320/2448 (ie, approximately 0.13) you'll automatically get the behaviour where zooming out as far as you can go ends up showing the entire 4:3 image on screen.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you obtain your image, but you might have gotten one of the representations of the image. One of those representations is specifically for getting a quick fullScreen CGImage, an other will return the FullResolution. FullScreen will be whatever is needed for the device (640x960 on iPhone4), Full resolution would be the 8MP picture.

Comment: Well, I kind of resolved it anyway. Instead of using the zoomScale, I  resized my UIImageView itself to support 3:2 aspect ratio. That brought the same functionality as of the iPhone gallery app.